# Why does this Javascript code to play audio needs to have alert() in front to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio

I would like to play a .wav file using javascript on my browser. The following code does not work;

```
var audio = new Audio("alert.wav");
audio.play();
```

However, to get it to work, I can do a simple trick by adding a dummy `alert()` in front.

```
    alert("Dummy");        
    var audio = new Audio("alert.wav");
    audio.play();
```

I have no idea why it works. My first question is how can I get the audio to play without having that dummy `alert()`? Second question is why does adding that dummy `alert()` got things working?

This code was run inside an AngularJS controller. Not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i think i have discovered the problem. I tested your code using a different .wav file. It works fine without the alert box. Perhaps its either:
a) The name of the .wav file is alert. (Rename the file maybe?)
b) It could be the file itself. Perhaps its not working, maybe redownload it (however you got it) or try a similar sounding .wav file? Hope this helps!

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. I wonder if it is because I am using AngularJS.

Comment: That could be also. I wasn't using AngularJS when i tested it.